# HSQL: How to save next value of sequence into a variable?

Tags: hsqldb

I am using HSQL and inside my stored procedure I need to save the "NEXT VALUE FOR MY_SEQUENCE" into a variable. How do I do this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE(
IN PARAM1 NUMERIC)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE NEXTID NUMERIC;
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR MY_SEQUENCE INTO NEXTID FROM MY_TABLE;
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID, COLUMN1) VALUES(NEXTID, PARAM1);
END;
```

Problem: 
The variable NEXTID is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the SELECT ... INTO statement. MY_TABLE has no rows or has more than one row and the NEXTID variable is not assigned to.

You can try direct assignment with the latest versions of HSQLDB:

```
SET NEXTID = NEXT VALUE FOR MY_SEQUENCE
```

With older versions of HSQLDB, you need to have a table with only one row and select from this table to assign to the sequence. When the Oracle compatibility mode is set, the DUAL table can be used. Otherwise create your own table with a single row.

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR MY_SEQUENCE INTO NEXTID FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: thanks, it does not seem to work =( this time the sql renders as not valid so i don't even get a null
  I'm using hsqldb-2.3.2

Comment: Updated for older versions.

Comment: ok I'm using the latest version hsql-2.3.3 and the following works 
        SET NEXTID = NEXT VALUE FOR MY_SEQUENCE